# split nested list into sublists by int values

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, nested-lists

I have two lists:

```py
 data = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12,13,14]]
 splitters = [3,7,10,13]
```

I want to split the nested lists in *data* by the values in *splitter* with the following conditions:

1. Don't split, if it's the first/last value in the list.
2. The split value in splitter should be at the end **and** at the beginning of the new lists.
3. Should be kind of iterable, so the lists are splitted in as many parts as splitters are in the list.
4. No redundance.

Final result should be something like:

```py
results = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[10,11,12,13],[13,14]
```

My first attempt looks like this:

```py
temp = []
for route in data:
    for node in route:
        if node in splitter and ((route.index(node) !=0) and (route.index(node) != (len(route)-1))):
            #route should be splitted and save it for now with the splitter
            temp.append([route, node])
            #here a big part is missing
                 #start a new subroute
                 #maybe something like a whileloop with len(route)
                 #check the same if-statement for the remaining subroute
        else:
            #no splitter in this route, so keep the original route
            temp.append([route, 0])
```

temp looks like that:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4], 0],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4], 0],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4], 3],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4], 0],...]
```

Based on that, I could remove redundant routes and split the route, but I think my approach is unnecessarily complicated and it gets more and more confusing if I want to implement something to meet the other conditions.

My research was not successful so far (using itertools.groupby etc.). This is kind of related: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3sk1xj/splitting_a_list_in_sublists_by_values/

Would appreciate some ideas/approaches how to solve this problem or subdivide it in smaller parts.

**Edit for future readers:**
I prefer the solution from maxiotic, because it works even with data like that

```
data = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
splitters = [1,2,3,4,7]
```

where every start/end of the nested lists is in splitters. Problem in the solution from Relondom is the following if statement and has to be changed:

```py
    if inner[0] in splitters or inner[-1] in splitters:  # check if first or last elemtn in splitters
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution that I was working on:

```
results = []
for route in data:
    found = 0
    for idx, r in enumerate(route[1:-1], 1):  # start idx at 1
        if r in splitters:
            temp = route[found:idx+1]  # +1 to capture the splitter value
            results.append(temp)
            found = idx 
    remaining = route[found:]
    results.append(remaining)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is an optimal way, but I decided to write this code since no one answered yet.

```
res = []
for inner in data:
    if inner[0] in splitters or inner[-1] in splitters:  # check if first or last elemtn in splitters
        res.append(inner) 
        continue
    else:
        temp = []  
        for val in inner:
            if val not in splitters:
                temp.append(val)
            else:
                temp.append(val)  # list ends with value from splitters
                res.append(temp)  # add new list to result
                temp = [val]  # new list starts with value from splitters
        if temp not in res:
            res.append(temp)
```